# Prevent adding a new record if multiple columns have the same value

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
id | name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op   | status | action
1    A      date_1   1    null  null   null    null       c
2    B      date_2   1      2   null   null    true       u
3    C      date_3   2      3     1    null    false      c
4.   D      date_4   2      3     1     1      false      c
```

Is there any way to prevent adding a new record if:

- multiple columns have the same value

Do not add a record if:

- status of the record in the database is not true and
- if action, prod, val,tar, op values for the new record are the same  with a record that exist already in the database

The idea is:

- status by default is null; if another operation is executed and fail is false, if is execute and done is true
- if a (operation)record exist in db (define by prod| val | tar |  op  |action) was not executed or fails(status null, false) and the new (operation)record is the same don't add the new record

For example, if I try:

1. shouldn't be added because the action, prod, val,tar, op  are the same
   and status is null

   ```
   name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op   | status | action
     E   date_5    1   null  null  null     null     c
   ```
2. should be added because action is different compared to 1

   ```
   name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op   | status | action
     Z   date_6    1   null  null  null     null     u
   ```
3. should be added because status of the record in database(2) is true

   ```
   name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op    | status | action
   F     date_6    1      2   null   null   null      u
   ```
4. should be added because the action of the record in db(4) is different

   ```
   name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op    | status | action
   H     date_6    2     3   1      1        null      u
   ```
5. shouldn't be added because the status of the record in db(4) is false

   ```
   name | date  | prod| val | tar |  op    | status | action
   H     date_6    2     3   1      1        null      c
   ```

Comment: How many of the five values can be the same? (Apparently, line 4 allows two.) And what about NULL values?

Comment: all need to be the same, even if is null